Basu's theorem and completeness
Recently, I was reading up on the Basu's theorem and what i gathered of it was that if a statistic $T$ is complete and minimal sufficient then it is free from Ancillary statistics. My question is why is the completeness part important? Intuitively, shouldn't it being minimal sufficient be enough to make if free from Ancillary statistic? I mean minimal sufficiency means maximum data reduction and if there were any ancillary components involved, we could obtain a minimal sufficient statistic by removing from it from the picture? Thank you
